# Is there any way to achieve the effect of an overloaded constructor in TypeScript such that one of the constructors is effectively private?

Tags: typescript

For the class I'm writing in TypeScript, I'd like to make one of the constructor overloads private, as it's really for internal use only.

The code I've tried is as follows:

```
  constructor(data: Array<T>);
  private constructor(data: Array<T>, options?: SequenceConstructionOptions);
  constructor(data: Array<T>, options: any) {
    if (typeof data === "undefined" || data === null) {
      throw "Object construction exception: data cannot be null or undefined.";
    }

    options = options ?? this.getDefaultConstructionOptions();

    this.data = options?.directStore ? data : [...data];
  }
```

Unfortunately, the [trans|com]piler complains about this with the message:

> Overload signatures must all be public, private or protected.

Clearly, mixed visibility isn't viable.

Is there any way at all to achieve what I'm trying to do in the sample above? I'm open to any alternatives, especially those that make me think outside the box.

**EDIT**

A sample of the invocation has been asked for.

Imagine I have a method that needs to return a new instance of the class itself. I need to return the instance using a special version of the constructor that is intended for internal use only. For example (constructor omitted for brevity):

```
class Sequence<T> {
  take(count: number): Sequence<T> {
    return new Sequence<T>(this.data.slice(0, count), SequenceOptions.Store);
  }
}
```

Now, a user will typically create a `Sequence<T>` as follows:

```
let seq = new Sequence<T>(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
```

However, they can always call it using `SequenceOptions` because there is no way to hide `SequenceOptions` from them.

Comment: A `private` constructor would only be able to be used within the class itself, which seems kind of odd. In any case you may want to consider using a factory method instead, a la `private Create(data: Array<T>, options?: SequenceConstructionOptions): MyClass`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oddly enough, that behavior is exactly what I want.

Comment: It seems typescript does not support overloads with different access levels. But how would you even call a private constructor? You would need to construct an instance, via it's constructor, to have access to it's private members, which you couldn't do since you could access the constructor the first place. Can you add an example of how you would invoke the private constructor?

Comment: @AlexWayne that's a commonly used pattern for singletons, where you create instances via a static factory function. It's odd though to need a public constructor in that case though.

Comment: @pascalpuetz You can hide a constructor in a scope, and prevent surfacing that to the rest of your code, but that's a different thing than marking a `constructor` signature as `private`. If you have a factory function, that function still has to call a constructor which couldn't be marked as private.

Comment: Sure it can be marked private if you call it from a static function on the class itself. Given `class MyClass { private constructor() {}}` the following works `static create() { return new MyClass()}`.

Comment: To provide some context, in C# we can overload constructors, and each constructor can have its own, distinct visibility. A private constructor can only be invoked within the class; so, for example, it would be for internal use only, to construct the object in specific ways--for example, if a method wanted to return a new instance of the class itself. That's the scenario I'm up against here. I don't see a viable way to do it.

Comment: You can have a hidden subclass, and put the private constructor on that subclass.

Comment: @MikeHofer Im pretty sure that's due to the fact that languages like Java or C# support overloading the constructor. In TypeScript, that is simply not possible because of the nature of JavaScript that it compiles to (well, you can overload the signature but not the function body). Workaround-wise there are a few ways like the mentioned subclassing, a private static create function that constructs the object and sets your properties as needed, making the constructor private altogether and only exposing an external static create function and so on.

Comment: @pascalpuetz Agreed. I've essentially arrived at the conclusion that what I want to do isn't possible in the *current* state of TypeScript. Maybe down the road. One can always dream.